# Batch creation of previews of mp3 songs

Tags: batch, mp3, sound-editing

I want to create snippets of mp3 songs using the first 30 seconds of each song. I want to apply the following actions on each mp3 song:

1. Cut the first 30 seconds length of each song.
2. Apply fade out effect at the end (from 28 secs to 30 secs)
3. Save the file as another mp3 file.

This needs to be done in a batch as the number of songs is pretty large.

Is there any software which can do this?

I am on Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). You can grab a precompiled version that supports mp3 from [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537155/sox-fail-util-unable-to-load-mad-decoder-library-libmad-function-mad-stream/11980926#11980926).

I've tried it with the following command line and it seems to do the job:

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 trim 0 30 fade t 0 30 2
     ^^1       ^^2        ^^3       ^^4
```

1. input filename
2. output filename
3. trim the file from 0 to 30 seconds
4. fade linear (t), fade-in-length 0, fade-out 'location' at 30 seconds with fade-out-length of 2

Then you only need to write a batch script, so it can (recursively) change all your desired mp3's.

They provide a `batch-example.bat` which might help you get started:

```
rem Example of how to do batch processing with SoX on MS-Windows.
rem
rem Place this file in the same folder as sox.exe (& rename it as appropriate).
rem You can then drag and drop a selection of files onto the batch file (or
rem onto a `short-cut' to it).
rem
rem In this example, the converted files end up in a folder called `converted',
rem but this, of course, can be changed, as can the parameters to the sox
rem command.

cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox %%A "converted/%%~nxA" rate -v 44100
pause
```